# Pysnmp nextCmd timeout increasing with time

Tags: python, pysnmp

I am using pysnmp nextCmd to get values from my transmitter periodically (15 seconds.)
However, the time it took to finish the request is increasing in every loop.

```
from time import sleep, time
from pysnmp.hlapi import *


request_count = 0
while request_count < 100:
    t0 = time()
    snmp_response = []
    for (errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds) in nextCmd(
        SnmpEngine(),
        UsmUserData(userName='transmitter_username', authKey='transmitter_authkey'),
        UdpTransportTarget((10.0.0.1, 161), timeout=1.0, retries=0),
        ContextData(),
        ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0')),
        lexicographicMode=False
    ):
        if errorIndication or errorStatus:
            print(errorStatus)
            print(errorIndication)
        else:
            snmp_response.append(varBinds)

    t1 = time()
    print(t1-t0)
    sleep(3)
    request_count += 1
```

The code outputs the following for me :

```
 1.1249938011169434
 1.1327455043792725
 2.132364273071289
 1.1966924667358398
 2.671931505203247
 1.12489914894104
 1.1628892421722412
 2.419915199279785
 1.993680477142334
 1.156675100326538
 2.601043939590454
 1.1927564144134521
 1.152949333190918
 1.3245742321014404
 3.4447848796844482
 2.326068878173828
 3.287410259246826
 1.2187728881835938
 2.5252578258514404
 3.5365397930145264
 4.069114685058594
 3.0139386653900146
 3.9634206295013428
 4.017256259918213
```

Why is it increasing with time? Am I missing something?

Comment: Can be a multi-threading interplay problem? I can't reproduce this effect with pysnmp 4.4.12 and your script run at a command prompt.

Comment: I checked the interplay problem on web but could not find any relatable info. Can you share a link please

Comment: I mean that if I run your script in a single-threading environment, I can't reproduce this problem. That makes me think that may be your application is multithreading and pysnmp calls are not sufficiently synchronised leading to timer corruption... Just a thought.